# Erro na renderização - classe could not be found: android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

No meu projeto o Android Studio está dando um problema de renderização nos xml, dando o seguinte erro:

> Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
>       - android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Fix Build Path, Create Class) 
>   Tip: Try to build the project.

E meu Gradle de dependências está da seguinte forma:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.4.8@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.shell-software:fab:1.0.5'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.4.0'
compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'
}
```

Minha xml de exemplo que esta com problema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="br.com.ciaware.people.activities.MainActivity" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tb_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<br.com.ciaware.people.extras.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/stl_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

E no Messages aparece esses erros

> Error:(11, 68) cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'RelativeLayout'.
>
> Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'x' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
>
> Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'x' is not a valid element in a schema document.
>
> Error:(1, 56) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

E no Gradle console está assim:

> Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, >:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
>
> :Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComDaimajiaAndroidanimationsLibrary113Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComDaimajiaEasingLibrary101Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGithubClansFab140Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGithubShellSoftwareFab105Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComMelnykovFloatingactionbutton130Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComMikepenzIconicsCore220Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComMikepenzMaterialdrawer448Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComMikepenzMaterialize028Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareMeDrakeetMaterialdialogLibrary122Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:validateDebugSigning
>   :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:zipalignDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 1.868 secs

E o Gradle está da seguinte forma:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "br.com.ciaware.people"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.0.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.4.8@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.shell-software:fab:1.0.5'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.4.0'
compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'
}
```

style.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="TextAppearanceFinish" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>


<style name="WizardPageContainer">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
</style>

<style name="WizardPageTitle">
    <item name="android:id">@android:id/title</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">36sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0099cc</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
</style>

<style name="WizardFormLabel">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_light</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">12dp</item>
</style>
```

Como corrigir esse problema?

Comment: Ele não renderiza nenhum layout ou é um layout específico?

Comment: @Androiderson não renderiza nenhum layout, todos os xml de layout aparece essa mensagem, ate os layouts de fragments, todos os layouts

Comment: Estranho, esse problema geralmente acontece com custom views. Existe algum componente ou include que você usa em todos os layouts? Se você criar um layout novo, apenas com um TextView por exemplo, o problema persiste?

Comment: @Androiderson Sim o problema persiste, to achando que é no schemas = `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` , pode ser sera?

Comment: @Androiderson coloquei mais detalhes do erros

Comment: Neste último poste, no gradle, está a versão 23.1.0 appcompat-v7 enquanto inicialmente era a versão 23.1.1. Qual das duas está de facto a utilizar?

Comment: Faltou postar o *styles.xml*, necessito saber qual é o *theme* que a app está a utilizar/descender.

Comment: @ramaral irei utilizar a versao que for mais facil e pratico de resolver o problema, a questao eh que em ambos ocorre o mesmo erro, e postei o style.xml e o tema eh esse "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" e tambem estou utilizando varios outros temas.

Comment: Como disse na minha resposta se quer usar a versão 23.1.1 da *appcompat-v7* o *theme* não pode ter como parent um theme que use *ActionBar*. Mude `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` para `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. Veja também a edição que fiz na resposta.

Comment: @TiagoFerezin continuas com o mesmo problema ou é outro?

Comment: @ramaral Funcionou, coloque como resposta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é você estar a usar a versão **23.1.1** da *appcompat-v7* conjuntamente com *ActionBar*.

Existem três soluções:

- Reverter para a versão **23.0.1**
- Subtituir *ActionBar* por *ToolBar* e fazer o seu tema descender de `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` ou `Theme.AppCompat.Dark.NoActionBar`
- Usar o ToolBar na ["forma *Standalone*"](http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) não o adicionando à *Activity* com `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`. Neste caso pode usar qualquer *AppCompat theme*, no entanto terá de o preencher manualmente com conteúdo/ações, é necessário "inflar" um menu para ele:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.blah);

      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);

      // Set an OnMenuItemClickListener to handle menu item clicks
      toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
              // Handle the menu item
              return true;
          }
      });

      // Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
      toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.your_toolbar_menu);
  }
  ```

<sub>Tive esse mesmo problema quando actualizei para a versão **23.1.1**. Foi [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33795214/2556111) que encontrei a razão e solução.</sub>

**Nota:**
Se o problema for causado por alguma das bibliotecas de terceiros, terá de ver se existe uma actualização que seja compatível com a versão **23.1.1** da *appcompat-v7*, caso não exista terá de fazer o *downgrade* para uma versão compatível.

Comment: eu tentei as três maneiras não funcionou, tem tela que uso somente ToolBar e mesmo assim aparece o erro, coloquei um exemplo de um tela completa.

Comment: E coloquei tudo la agora

Comment: Você inicialmente fazia referência a um erro agora já fala em outros. Eles já existiam ou surgiram após ter tentado as soluções que eu indiquei? Se tirar o `SlidingTabLayout` os erros persistem?

Comment: retirei o SlidingTabLayout e os erros persistiram ainda, e sim eles ja existiam após eu ter tentado as soluções, isso ta me desanimando ja rs

Comment: @TiagoFerezin se eu fosse você eu colocaria apenas as bibliotecas necessárias para fazer funcionar esse layout com problema. Você poderia retirar a biblioteca nineoldandroids, pois ela não está sendo mais atualizada. Você também nåo precisa mais da bliblioteca com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0 pois o comportamento que busca com ela pode ser alcançado nativamente utilizando a biblioteca de suporte com.android.support:design:23.1.0 juntamente com um CoordinatorLayout e um RecyclerView.

Comment: @TiagoFerezin Assim que conseguir executar esse layout sem erros, vai adicionando as bibliotecas realmente necessárias. Como disse acima, algumas podem ser trocadas por libs nativas, outras q vc está utilizando não estao mais sendo suportadas. Eu acho q dessa forma fica mais facil encontrar o seu problema.

Comment: @Arubu entao essa eh a questao essa biblioteca é necessaria e funciona normalmente em outro projeto meu tb, que estou desenvolvendo em paralelo a esse.

Comment: Nesse outro projecto o Gradle tem as mesmas versões para *build Tools*, *appcompat-v7*, etc?

Comment: @ramaral tem sim o build tools ta identico

Comment: Eu estou com o @ramaral nessa. Na linha onde tem <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> coloque <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"> e garanta que em seu manifest na tag <application> exista android:theme="@style/AppTheme". Só que ai vc vai ter q usar uma toolbar. Segue guia http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/appbar/setting-up.html

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema mudando a dependencia para uma versão mais atual  'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar', mando sincronizar o Gradle, depois vou no menu Arquivos do Android Studio e Invalidate Caches e Restart.